# Troubleshoot localhost / apache - connection refused error on MacOS

Tags: macos, apache, localhost

I am trying to debug `localhost` connection refused error. For context, I have a Flask App that I am trying to run locally. I launch the app using `gunicorn` and notice that it is running on port 8000.

```
Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2022-02-24 05:38:49 -0800] [21269] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (21269)
[2022-02-24 05:38:49 -0800] [21269] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2022-02-24 05:38:49 -0800] [21271] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 21271
```

I have tried several things including:

1. restart apache server - `sudo apachectl restart`
2. flush dns: `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder;sudo killall mDNSResponderHelper;sudo dscacheutil -flushcache`
3. Run `httpd`

```
    AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using MacBook-Air-2020.local. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
    (48)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
    (48)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
    no listening sockets available, shutting down
```

4. `telnet 127.0.0.1`

```
    Trying 127.0.0.1...
    telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
    telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

5. When I enter `http://127.0.0.1/` in browser, I get

It works!

What else can I try? I am using `gunicorn` server to deploy / run the App locally.

Comment: When you get "It works", what's the problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase `localhost:port` does not work! That's the problem.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. What do you mean by `localhost:port` and what does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: @NicoHaase "doesn't work" - redirects / connection refused. Example: `http://127.0.0.1:8000`

Comment: Please share more details. A webserver usually listens only on specific ports. If you haven't configured port 8000 anywhere, it's obvious that this does not work

Comment: @NicoHaase can you clarify what you mean by configure? I specify the port # when running the App.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242366/discussion-between-kms-and-nico-haase).

Comment: Please add **all** clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: @NicoHaase are you able to join the chat?

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick for me:

```
sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder;sudo killall mDNSResponderHelper;sudo dscacheutil -flushcache
```